# Python, Py2exe, PyQT - distribution

Tags: python, pyqt4, py2exe

Basically. I have Python based program with PyQT UI compiled using py2exe. Can I sell it ?

Comment: yup ... depending on what other assets you used in it but those 3 are all ok

Answer (score 2):

Not a lawyer, but I think the answer is no, as PyQt is licensed under the GPL license and your program incorporates PyQt. You can use the alternative LGPL-licensed PySide which has a similar API to PyQt or use [PyQt's commercial version](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/commercial/pyqt). Not sure whether it's legal to use PySide when using py2exe on a closed source program since the library will be embedded in the application.